# applying condtions within same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Primary    Secondary
-----------------------------------
UST         MUN
Data        NULL
Tele        Data
Sun         Data
RMDS        Data
Data        NULL
Mor         NULL
UST         NULL
Data        Bridge
```

I want to check if values of "Secondary" is already in "primary" then it should come as "primary" but if it is not in "primary" values it must come under "Secondary" column only.

Here I want output as:

```
Primary  Secondary
------  -----------
UST      MUN
Data     Bridge
Tele
Sun
RMDS
Mor
Bridge
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use tables as spreadsheets. This will not tend to work well, despite their superficial resemblance. Specifically, rows and columns in tables are *very* different things.

Comment: If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just add your code (or the relevant parts) to the question, because without that we cannot help. Please see [ask]

Comment: previously i did union of two,but i was giving me data from both under one column,but i wanted to have data like i have provided,but i am not getting any clue to do this, as i m new to sql

Comment: What @PeterB said, you should edit your question to include your code.

Comment: @MaheshKafaltiya - How did Bridge come under Primary in your output table ? Is the OUTPUT table that you have provided correct? Pls recheck it.

Answer (score 0):

Yey - You made it!

You've reached enough experience to struggle with self-joins in SQL.. this is a  major milestone in your development career

Please - use the below article (which is really great) to figure out how to link the secondary field to your primary field wit ha self join.. and that's basically it :)

Link: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/07/08/sql-server-the-self-join-inner-join-and-outer-join/

Comment: A warning: Link-only answers are not recommended, frowned upon, and often downvoted.

Comment: I know.. but my comment it is too darn heavy to be a.. comment... :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Bridge under Primary should not be present in the OUTPUT. Please find below.

```
SELECT [primary],ISNULL(MAX([Secondary]),'') as [Secondary]
FROM
(SELECT T1.[primary],T2.[Secondary]
FROM 
(SELECT [primary]
FROM #T) T1
JOIN 
(SELECT [primary],[Secondary]
FROM #T  WHERE [Secondary] NOT IN (SELECT [primary]
FROM #T)) T2
ON T1. [primary] = T2.[primary]
GROUP BY T1.[primary],T2.[Secondary]

UNION 

SELECT ONE,NULL FROM
(SELECT [Primary] AS ONE FROM #T
EXCEPT
SELECT [Secondary] FROM #T) X) M
GROUP BY [Primary]
```

Answer (score 0):

The clue of solution is using `Join`:

The Full outer Join (Type of Joins) is so close form what you want.

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM
(select distinct [Primary] from test) t1 
Full outer JOIN
(select distinct Secondary 
from test where Secondary not in (select distinct [Primary] from test)) t2
ON t1.[Primary] = t2.Secondary
```

**Result:-**

```
Primary Secondary
NULL    Bridge
Data    NULL
Mor     NULL
NULL    MUN
RMDS    NULL
Sun     NULL
Tele    NULL
UST     NULL
```